# Going on a Vacation with a dog, beach and sea

Tags: dogs

We have a 2 year old German Spitz. We didn't take her on any long trips or beaches. This year we're going to the beach/sea and we want to take her with us. The temperatures will be around 28-32 degrees Celsius. I know we need some shade and fresh water. She has long fur and i am scared about her well-being (heatstroke). My question is should we take her with us and if so what do i need to do for her well-being?

Comment: Not a proper answer but you should check local regulations regarding dogs in beaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can definitely take your dog to the beach with you if you keep some things in mind. With having fresh water and shade around you are already on a pretty good way.

I found [this website](https://www.honestpaws.com/blogs/pet-care/heat-stroke-in-dogs) to be very helpful and will list some important things they mention:

- As you mentioned water (cool water) is very important so having a bowl at hand would be good.
- Shade; by an umbrella, a towel or really anything at hand
- Since air conditioning is not an option, you can take some ice, put it into a towel and into a shirt or blanket and your dog can cool down lying on it.
- Cooling with a towel is also an option, just wet the towel and rub your dog with it; that will regulate body temperature.
- Playing in the water is an option, of course be careful and don't stay in the sun too long or have your dog be too active
- If your pet has any other health issues be sure to check with a vet on how to handle these combined with the heat.
- Protecting your dogs paws on asphalt but sand as well, as we all have experienced sand can get too hot for us to walk on so with sensitive dog paws it is not fun either.
- Finally do not muzzle your dog since it can prevent him from panting.

[This page](https://www.dogster.com/dog-health-care/heat-stroke-in-dogs) as well as the other also explains how to treat and see symptoms of heat stroke but it is what we are trying to avoid, so check it out but I won't go in depth.

Comment: This answer misses a very important point.  Not all beaches allow pets.  Google 'dog friendly beaches' for examples.